# Unable to identify Local Storage Items regarding snapinsPage

Tags: browser, local-storage, session-cookies

I am trying to find out what company would be setting these on an e-commerce site and what the usage would be around these local storage items I am seeing:

```
snapinsPage_1
snapinsPage_10
snapinsPage_11
snapinsPage_12
snapinsPage_13
snapinsPage_14
snapinsPage_15
snapinsPage_16
snapinsPage_17
snapinsPage_2
snapinsPage_3
snapinsPage_4
snapinsPage_5
snapinsPage_6
snapinsPage_7
snapinsPage_8
snapinsPage_9
snapinsPageTime_0
snapinsPageTime_1
snapinsPageTime_10
snapinsPageTime_11
snapinsPageTime_12
snapinsPageTime_13
snapinsPageTime_14
snapinsPageTime_15
snapinsPageTime_16
snapinsPageTime_17
snapinsPageTime_2
snapinsPageTime_3
snapinsPageTime_4
snapinsPageTime_5
snapinsPageTime_6
snapinsPageTime_7
snapinsPageTime_8
snapinsPageTime_9
snapinsPc
snapinsStart
```

Has anyone seen these and know what they are doing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It comes from Salesforce.

If you do a search on the site with that local storage set, you can see it setting these values in the Javascript.:
[screenshot of chrome developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DF0sw.png)

Comment: More specifically it comes from Salesforce Embedded Chat which is described as: Add an embedded chat window to your company website for customers to get quick answers to their questions while browsing your pages. Include a pre-chat form to collect key information and customize the experience to match your branding.